# Best way to deal with sleeping in event handlers in a single-threaded API?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, fibers

I'm using a non-threadsafe event API. `wait()` is called, and from that call, event handlers are dispatched. I want to be able to, within an event handler, "sleep" for some time. Currently, I have a scheduler that schedules functions to be called at a later time, and have a bit of a hack that lets me use Scheduler.Sleeper(some_ienumerator) as the event handler, so I can yield timespans as a sort of sleep. Is there any better solution? If C# had Ruby-style Fibers, I would be able to make the scheduler have a Sleep() function that I can call, and the sleep stuff could be in a function called by the event handler, rather than the handler directly. Given the lack of easily-usable Fibers, is there anything else I can do?

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION: I call `wait(n)` where n is an amount of time, and during that wait call, the API calls the event handlers. The reason I want to "sleep" in some of those handlers is because this is for a game, where after clicking on something, an object might, for instance, glow for a second.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I am having a hard time determining what you are wanting to do.  I do my best to never have a sleep in any code I write.  I am sure there is a time and a place for them, but I have been bitten too many times by them, and usually they were placed because of some timing issue.  They turn out as band-aids rather than the solution.  Having said that, I am still unclear of your intent based on your description, so I may be missing the intent of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. The question is what do you want to do while "waiting"? If you were talking for example about WinForms GUI applications, then you would want to process other events while waiting (which can be done using the `Application.DoEvents` method), so maybe you could use a similar solution?

A lightweight cooperative multi-threading (probably similar to Ruby fibers) can be simulated in C# using iterators (the `yield return`) keyword. Much better way to do something like this in .NET is to use F#, where you can do this kind of things more elegantly using *asynchronous workflows*. Here is an article that demonstrates writing single-threaded GUI where you can "wait" for an event occurrence without blocking:

- [Programming User interfaces using F# workflows](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Programming-user-interfaces-using-f-sharp-workflows.aspx)

As I said, you could simulate this in C# using `yield return`. Here is my attempt:

- [Asynchronous programming in C# using iterators](http://tomasp.net/blog/csharp-async.aspx)

Another approach based on `yield return` is the [Concurrency and coordination runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648752.aspx), which is a bit more complicated, but was designed primarily for C#.

Comment: The problem with yield return (at least the way I'm using it, and my understanding of the second link [the first one mentioning C#]) is that a function [A] can't simply call another function [B] that happens to use yield return and itself be stopped, waiting for the asynchronous function to callback B and from there, have A be resumed.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is exactly what the last code sample in the article does. The method `ReadToEndAsync` returns `IEnumerable<IAsync>` (and contains `yield return`). In the article, we can use `ExecuteAsync<string>()` to turn it a value representing an _asynchronous computation_ (of type `Async<string>`) and then you can call this computation from the outer method (using `yield return`). I think, in general you need to use some intermediate type to represent _computations_.

Comment: I didn't exactly read the entire article before commenting >.>. Thank you, that link (Asynchronous programming in C# using iterators) seems like it will be perfect! [I still need to try it, though].